# VSTO Outlook Plugin: AppointmentItem GlobalAppointmentItem behavior is not matching with exchange data using GRAPH APIs

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, vsto, outlook-addin

With outlook VSTO plugin, GlobalAppointmentID is same for series master and individual occurrences, however with GRAPH API event resource type it is different for each occurrences.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0 (refer iCalUid)

Since this is different behavior, how can we access GlobalAppointmentID of individual occurrences which is there on exchange without querying GRAPH APIs.

Is there any documentation available about this difference between outlook client plugins and exchange data ?

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this one ? For recurring meetings seems there is no way we can access GlobalAppointmentId (iCalUID) for individual occurrences from the VSTO based outlook plugins. For series and individual occurrences I am getting same GlobalAppointmentID and when I check exchange data using GRAPH those all have different iCAlUID. Thank you.